# Setting 3 dimensional data for milti species occupancy modelling

Tags: dataframe, 3d, spatial, spatial-query, occupancy-map

I am going through a lot of resource material on multi species occupancy modelling which has given me multiple .rda files to load and run in R, but nothing is helping me to look at the data to know how to arrange my own data in a file. the "str" function just tells me what their data have, but not how I could set the data in an excel file or something. It needs to be set in a 3-Dimensional way, but I don't understand how. If someone could please help me out with understanding it, I will really appreciate it. Say I have presence absence data for 4 species (Warbler, finch, crow and sparrow) across 11 sites ("S1","S2","S3","S4","S5","S6","S7","S8","S9","S10", "S11") for 5 years, with 3 replicate surveys in each site. How do I set my data in an excel file in a 3-D way to be worked on in R for multi species occupancy modelling? Any help is appreciated.

```
warbler<-c(0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0)

finch<-c(1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)

crow<-c(1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1)

sparrow<-c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0)
```

All the data is site-wise and replicate-wise so the first fifteen data points are for S1 for year 1-5 (3 for each year) and so on.